# My own server hosting?

Tags: hosting

Is it possible to build a server and give to a company to do all the work for maintenance etc and pay them monthly? Something like dedicated or managed hosting but using your own hardware (or tell them what to buy)?

Comment: You're probably looking for some form of colocation.

Comment: Yep, I'll do that. You buy and build it, ship it to me with a blank check.

Comment: The non-smart mass answer is that what you're asking for would cost enormously, so no "normal" hosting company would do it. You'd have to find a place that would work with you on a custom solution and it would cost much more than either using traditional hosting or managing the server yourself/colo.

Answer (score 3):

Managed Services would be a better term for what you are looking for.  They will take your hardware and manage it for you for a fee of course.  Normally for co-location they are just racking/stacking and providing power and network, you manage the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but its much much cheaper to have a hosting company do it if you're just doing a small to midrange size site.  The only reason you would need something like this is if you're doing lots of business or have tons of traffic.